# How does gravity apply a net torque on a pendulum?SHM

Tags: angular-momentum, harmonic-oscillator

How can gravity apply a net torque on a pendulum? Since its only possible to apply a net torque if you do work perpendicular to the pendulum. The two only situation that I can think of in which gravity would do work is that if the pendulum makes a 90 degree with the horizontal, as a result that would no longer be a simple harmonic motion. Secondly if we broke the weight vector into its vertical and horizontal component. Also does that mean the linear momentum is not constant? Please explain why the angular momentum is not constant and how does gravity apply torque on the system. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The torque occurs on the pendulum "bob" (the big weight at the end of a thin rod/string) because it is rotating about a point (where the other end of the thin rod/string is fixed).  Let me address some of your statements:

> Since its only possible to apply a net torque if you do work perpendicular to the pendulum.

The vector definition of torque is $\mathbf{\tau} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F}$, because the bob is attached to a point of rotation, the torque about the point of rotation is simply the product $rF sin(\theta)$ where $r$ is the length of the rod, $F$ is the force on the bob (gravity in this case) and $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{F}$.  When the bob hangs directly under, or stands directly over, the point of rotation, $\theta = 0,180^{\circ}$ and there is no torque.  At any other location on the circle the bob is constrained to move on there is a torque.

You seem to get this fact when you say this:

> Secondly if we broke the weight vector into its vertical and horizontal component.

This is correct, the torque on the bob is equal to the the product of the rod length and component of gravity that is circumferential, i.e. that is not pointing along the rod holding the bob.  This is what I described after the first quote.  This is also why you "firstly" is somewhat correct, the torque is maximum when the bob is at the same height as the point of rotation.

> Also does that mean the linear momentum is not constant?

Yes, the linear momentum is not constant.  Linear momentum is the product of mass and velocity along some straight line ($\mathbf{p} = m\mathbf{v}$), since we know that the bob stops moving at the high points in the oscillation, the linear momentum **must** be zero at these points because $v=0$.  However, at the bottom of the trajectory, the linear momentum is not zero (the bob is clearly moving either left of right).  Since the linear momentum is, at different parts of the motion, either zero or "not zero" the linear momentum must be changing.

The angular momentum is not constant for the same reason.  Its definition is $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p}$.  Conceptually, it is the momentum around a point (or axis). Since we know that the magnitude of $\mathbf{r}$ is constant, and we know that the magnitude of $\mathbf{p}$ is **not** constant, the angular momentum must be changing too.  Another way to see this in the case of the pendulum is to ask "how fast is the bob moving around the point of rotation" as this is a measure of the angular momentum when the radius of motion is fixed.  Since you know the the bob will turn around and move in the other direction when executing simple harmonic motion, you have to conclude that the angular momentum is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity will apply a torque as long as it is acting at any nonzero distance away from the center of mass of an object.  This changes the angular momentum.